# how server can save a file which has been sent by a client?

Tags: c

I am writing a client-server in C in which many clients send a running file to server and server needs to execute the file and save the result in their computer.
now I have 2 questions: 
1-should server save the receiving file before executing it?if yes how?
2-I am going to use CreateProcess() function to make a child and run every clients file in different process..is that a good choice?!

thank you for your kind help in advance
Negar

Comment: I don't know if there is a "good choice" for executing a file supplied by a client...

Answer (score 0):

1.) Yes. And if you are asking this, you probably doesn't have the knowledge to run executables in-memory.

2.) `CreateProcess()` enable the host (your server app) to share handle with the child (spawned app).
This is helpful if you want to know the child's console output.

Comment: not actually! I have written this in Python and if u hv knowledge abt python you dont need to save file ..evrything is automatically..lol

Comment: c seems too complicated to me and I am a noob! btw thank you for yr kind help :)

Comment: @negneg : I don't get it about python in your replies. i thought this question directed to C

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, probably a good Idea if want to build some resilience in your server at later point.

2) Yes again, apart from the reasons outlined by YeenFei for security and robustness perspective. As the executable received from the client might crash and you do not want your server process to crash along with it.